# Why Finalizer should not be called after manually calling destructor ( by delete) in C++ CLI

Tags: c++-cli, suppressfinalize

After refer this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7965/Deterministic-Destruction-in-C-CLI) which talks about the difference of destructor& finalizer IN C++ CLI, 
I wonder why compiler add some instrs. to suppress the finalize in destructor?

Dose finalize function not stand for "In finally, it will be called by GC" ?

AND

Should we add same "release resource" code in both destructor and finalizer ?

Comment: Sounds to me your are getting confused by the *finally* keyword.  Which is part of try/catch/finally and doesn't have anything to do with releasing resources.  Calling the destructor is optional in managed code.  You write a finalizer to ensure that doesn't cause trouble.  And yes, the finalizer is called by the GC after it garbage-collected the object.

Comment: Well, it looks like I really be influenced by the try/catch/finally semantics. :$ Thanks Hans!

Answer (score 0):

When you write a destructor (Dispose method in C#), you're supposed to do **all** the work of cleaning up the object. With a properly written destructor, there's nothing left for the finalizer to do, so the compiler suppresses it.

In C#, the pattern is to write a Dispose(bool) method, and have the Boolean indicate whether you're disposing or finalizing. In C++/CLI, the compiler writes that method, so you're not allowed. I believe you could simply call the finalizer from the destructor, if you didn't want to repeat code.

Comment: Yes, we can re-register Finalize in Dispose, but I wonder why the compiler/designer try to avoid these usage in default?